# Is a preposition required here? "There’s no doubting the passion of Indian premier Narendra Modi"

Tags: prepositions

In this [blog,](http://qz.com/685689/two-years-in-modi-is-not-even-close-to-being-the-modi-we-wanted/) I read the following sentence:

> As he completes two years of his term as prime minister, there’s ***no doubting the passion*** of Indian premier Narendra Modi.

Check out the bold portion of the sentence. I've checked that 'doubting the passion' is not an idiomatic expression. My question is: Don't we require a preposition before 'the passion'? If we require then which preposition suits better here.

Comment: I don't think you need a preposition there. The sentence looks grammatically accurate.

Comment: 'There's  no doubting the passion'  is not an idiomatic  expression, as in it's not an idiom; but 'There's no doubting *something*' is idiomatic. So the clause is fine.

Comment: I don't like the sentence as a whole. It's messy. The subject of the dependent clause (*as he...*) is Modi; but to use an existential clause *there's no doubting* as the independent clause in this same sentence  is rather sloppy scribbling. I can't actually call it writing.

Comment: @AlanCarmack: Really? It reads perfectly comfortably to me. To say you "can't call it writing" is at best fantastical hyperbole, and at worst just plain rude.

Comment: Yes, the sentence is absolutely fine.

Answer (score 13):

No!

The verb 'doubt' is transitive there. I mean the verb goes like "doubt something" so `doubt + something` with no preposition.

Check this [entry on OALD](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/doubt_2)

> *doubt something - There seems no reason to **doubt her story.***

Comment: True, but note that even with transitive verbs, we often use *of* between the gerund form and its object (as in *The Taming of the Shrew*, "the breaking of the glass", etc.). It's actually a rather complicated area of English grammar; gerunds are sometimes nounlike (taking adjectives and determiners and *of*) and sometimes verblike (taking adverbs and no determiners and no *of*), and it's not always easy to explain why.

Comment: There's ***no doubting that nuance*** @ruakh ^-^

Answer (score 9):

It is quite natural:

> There's no doubting the class system is alive and well in Britain, and there's no doubting where I belong: in the public bars with the workers!!! ([Chris Brady, 2012](https://books.google.ru/books?id=QhtRKHOK4J4C&lpg=PA177&dq=%22there's%20no%20doubting%20the%22&hl=ru&pg=PA177#v=onepage&q=%22there's%20no%20doubting%20the%22&f=false))

And its use has been increasing over the years:

[image]

However, here's a comparison with "there is no doubt in":

[image]

And here is a comparison of the previous two with "there is no doubt that":

[image]

You probably thought that the sentence should include a construction with `doubt + preposition` instead of "doubting":

> As he completes two years of his term as prime minister, there’s **no doubt in the passion** of Indian premier Narendra Modi.

or

> As he completes two years of his term as prime minister, there’s **no doubt that** Indian premier Narendra Modi is passionate about his job.

Comment: The increase is so fractional.

Comment: @VarunKN - I'm afraid I don't understand. I mean to post some other Ngrams though, which show that the relative frequency is indeed low

Comment: I wasn't saying there is hardly any increase, but just pointing out that it is so infrequently used that it would need a little bit more frequent usage to be called *'idiomatic'*. Don't you think so? Just saying.

Comment: @VarunKN - I agree, it does seem to be not widespread, but I've just did a Google Books search, and there are about 150+ results, with some of the names markedly "Western", so native speakers seem to use it.

Comment: It is a typo, I guess. Instead of writing 'no doubt in' they may have written 'no doubting'.

Comment: @RuchirM Not at all! "There is no doubt" can stand alone because 'doubt' is an abstract noun. But then, "there's no doubting" needs something to follow and in this case, it's the passion!

Comment: **There's no doubting the _____** has been in use for several hundred  years. It's legit.

Comment: @TRomano - but I never said it was not legit.

Comment: @CowperKettle: Ruchir M in a comment above supposed it to be a typo.

Comment: Is there any support for it being an idiom rather than a construction that uses standard syntax? As Maulik notes and Merriam-Webster confirms, *doubt* is a transitive verb, so there wouldn't be a preposition normally.

Comment: @ToddWilcox - does "idiomatic" necessarily imply that something is an idiom? I thought this adjective vaguely indicates that this or that phrase is a naturally-sounding phrase.

Comment: ***Idiomatic*** (expanded) - "of, relating to, or conforming to an expression that **cannot be understood from the meanings of its separate words** but that has a separate meaning of its own" (emphasis mine). See: http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/idiomatic

Comment: @ToddWilcox - I believe it has the meaning of "natural" too. But since you insist, I've changed it to from "idiomatic" to "natural" to be less misguiding.

Comment: +1 for the ngram counts, but I don’t think your example, “There’s no doubting the class system is alive and well…”, is the same construction as the one in the question.  Yours is of the form “there’s no doubting [finite clause]”, while the original example is of the form “there’s no doubting [noun phrase]”.

Answer (score 5):

The link URL below is too long for a comment, so I'll make it an answer, though Maulik gets a +1 for the point about the transitivity.

There's no doubting the _______ is a legitimate phrase and has been in use for several hundred years.

Consider [these uses](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=is+no+doubting+the+*&year_start=1700&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t2%3B%2Cis%20no%20doubting%20the%20%2A%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bis%20no%20doubting%20the%20fact%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bis%20no%20doubting%20the%20sincerity%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bis%20no%20doubting%20the%20importance%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bis%20no%20doubting%20the%20reality%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bis%20no%20doubting%20the%20truth%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bis%20no%20doubting%20the%20genuineness%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bis%20no%20doubting%20the%20existence%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bis%20no%20doubting%20the%20significance%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bis%20no%20doubting%20the%20seriousness%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bis%20no%20doubting%20the%20strength%3B%2Cc0) as shown in the Ngram query `is no doubting the *`

P.S.
`There's no doubting the ________` puts the characteristic that fits into the slot in a brighter spotlight than does the less forceful alternative, "There's no doubt that X is {adjective}"

Comment: About the transitivity of *doubt*, I doubt that (especially when you mentioned that it's been in used for centuries). In OED1, *doubt* as an intransitive verb is documented.

Comment: **doubt** is both a transitive and an intransitive verb. http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/doubt   I doubted his word.  I doubted his thoroughness.   He is not a believer; he doubts.